# リスト内の頭文字を結合したい

Tags: python

初歩的な質問かと思いますが、

```
v = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']

aeim
```

上記リストvの頭文字のみをjoinしたいと考えています。
リストの要素をスライスして0文字目を取得すればよいとは思うのですが、どう処理していいのか悩んでいます。
なにか良い方法はありますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。
pythonのバージョンは2.7.12を使用しています。

Comment: 奇手ですが、reduce を使って `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[0], [''] + v)` など。

Comment: `''.join(zip(*v)[0])`なども

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ジェネレータ式を使った例です。

```
v = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
result = "".join(i[0] for i in v)
# result は 'aeim'
```

参考:

- [ジェネレータ式とリスト内包表記](https://docs.python.jp/3.6/howto/functional.html?highlight=comprehensions#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions)
- [リストの内包表記](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

一度 Python の入門書などを読んだ方がよいかと思われます。

その１

```
v = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
heads = ""
for s in v:
        # print("s => " + s)
        head = s[0]
        # print("head => " + head)
        heads += head

print(heads)
```

その２

```
v = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
heads = "".join([ s[0] for s in v ])
print(heads)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = ""
v = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop']
for line in v:
    s += v[0]
```